# sharepoint postback is not working in IE 11

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, javascript, sharepoint-addin

The Postback redirection in SharePoint is working fine in Chrome and firefox. but IE 11 the redirection is nor working properly.

I have used the below javascript code

```
 var publishButton = $("input[id$=SaveItem]");
            // change redirection behavior
            publishButton.removeAttr("onclick");

            publishButton.on('click',function() {

                var elementName = $(this).attr("name");
                var aspForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
                var oldPostbackUrl = aspForm.action;
                if (SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm('WPQ2')) return false;
                var currentSourceValue = GetUrlKeyValue("Source", true, oldPostbackUrl);
                var newPostbackUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx";
                var newPostbackUrl = oldPostbackUrl.replace(currentSourceValue,newPostbackUrl );
                if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;
                setTimeout(function(){
                    WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(elementName, "", true, "", newPostbackUrl, false, true));
                },1);       
            });
```

Suggest idea to do in IE 11 redirection.

Answer (score 2):

If all your browsers support `history.pushState` you could dynamically just add a `Source` parameter to your URL. SharePoint uses the `Source` for redirect. If the redirect url is always the same, you could just add it when you open the form.

```
if (history.pushState) {
    var redirectURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '?Source='+ _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +'';
    window.history.pushState({path:redirectURL},'',redirectURL);
}
```

Comment: This is not working for on click event.I want to use only PostBack method.